# What is proper workaround for @BeforeAll in Kotlin

Tags: java, junit, mockito, kotlin, junit5

Currently the JUnit 5 API only allows `@BeforeAll` on a method that is static.

So if I do something like this, it will not compile:

```
@BeforeAll
  fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build()
}
```

In order to have a static method in Kotlin, I have to use `companion object` like this:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
      mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(smsController).build()
    }
}
```

This will compile, but I don't have access to variables from the parent class. So what would be the idiomatic way to invoke JUnit 5 `@BeforeAll` with Kotlin?

Comment: I think it is wrong that you use `@BeforeAll`. Why don't you use `@BeforeEach`?

Comment: I was under impression that JUnit 5 instantiate test class only once, but it looks like it does it for each test case. Which make no difference between `@BeforeAll` and `@BeforeEach` ... almost no difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`@BeforeAll`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations):

> Denotes that the annotated method should be executed before all @Test
>   methods in the current class; analogous to JUnit 4’s @BeforeClass.
>   Such methods must be static and are inherited.

The above is true for both Kotlin and Java. Keep in mind that by default Junit will create a separate instance of a test class per test case. It makes sense that `@BeforeAll` will only work with static methods since it's supposed to be invoked before any code of current test case. A static method **has no access to instance members because it can be invoked** without an instance.

As stated in Spring documentation:

> The "standaloneSetup" on the other hand is a little closer to a unit test.

The example shows that you should just use instance members like so:

```
class StandaloneTest {
  val smsController = ... // create instance of controller
  val MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(smcController).build()
}
```

The usefulness of `@BeforeAll` is limited and should generally be avoided as it potentially encourages runtime dependencies between test cases.

Answer (score 51):

JUnit 5 has `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)` annotation that can be used for this purpose. One of the features that it enables is non-static `BeforeAll` and `AfterAll` methods:

```
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
class BeforeAllTests {

    lateinit var isInit = false

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        isInit = true
    }

   @TestFactory
   fun beforeAll() = listOf(
       should("initialize isInit in BeforeAll") {
           assertTrue(isInit)
       }
   )
}

fun should(name: String, test: () -> Unit) = DynamicTest.dynamicTest("should $name", test)
```

Comment: It is also possible to define `PER_CLASS` as the default via a `junit-platform.properties` file, see Spring Kotlin documentation for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#testing.

Comment: Android Studio could not resolve PER_CLASS. `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`

Answer (score 15):

You have access to the variables inside the **companion** object:

```
    companion object {

        private lateinit var objectToBeInitialized: Test

        @BeforeAll
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            objectToBeInitialized = Test()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect Answer.

Answer (score 4):

JUnit 5 supports test extensions, for example [BeforeAllCallback](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeAllCallback.html)

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext

class BeforeAllTests : BeforeAllCallback {
    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        System.out.println("Before all executed");
    }
}
```

In your Kotlin test class

```
@ExtendWith(BeforeAllTests::class)
class MyAppCoreTest : MyAppTest() {

    @Test
    fun someTest() { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In a `@SpringBootTest`, here's a simple solution. Notice that the `@BeforeAll` fun can use properties injected by Spring.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application::class])
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var someBean: SomeBean

    lateinit var propertyForAll: PropertyForAll

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        propertyForAll = PropertyForAll(someBean.valueXyz())
    }

    @Test
    fun `First test`() {
        val something = propertyForAll.findSomething("Banana")
        // test continues
    }

    @Test
    fun `Second test`() {
        val something = propertyForAll.findSomething("Orange")
        // test continues
    }
}
```

Worth looking:

- The *Test Intance Lifecycle* section in this oficial [Spring Boot with Kotlin tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin)
- This [DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/kotlin-and-junit-5-beforeall) has an excellent response and explanation.